# How to save Array (Field Type) in MongoDB using Python (

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

Updated:

I have a CSV file with this structure:

```
Model   Back_material                       Body_material
119     "Color 1", "Color 2", .."Color n"   "Color 1", "Color 2",.. "Color x"
320     "Color 1", "Color 2"                "Color 1", "Color 2", "Color 3"
```

Actual CSV file is in here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iB4yAmxOZiDL8e9iw-Un6rox5LWxr23-/view?usp=sharing

I'm trying to save this information in MongoDB using Pymongo as follows:

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient


# Load csv dataset
data = pd.read_csv('bd.csv', sep=',\s+', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
# Connect to MongoDB
client =  MongoClient()
db = client['python_test']
collection = db['prod']
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_dict = data.to_dict("records")
# Insert collection
collection.insert_many(data_dict)
```

However, when I'm sending the data to MongoDB, MongoDB applies string type to all the fields (I have a really long string for the field Body_material) and I need arrays. In the first image the field "Back" is string type.
For example:
Actual Result:

[image: Image 1 - MongoDB document]

In the second image, the field Back is an array with the each item of the CSV file in the column "Back" being an item of the array in the MongoDB document. 
Expected Result:
[image: Image 2 - MongoDB Expected]

Is there any way to perform that using Python or MongoDB? Since I'm using Pandas, I could transform the columns to adapt to MondoDB. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What does your csv look like - your colors are separated by comma's?

Comment: Yes, but I could change if necessary, in fact I generated the CSV using Pandas.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the section on "Help other reproduce the problem". If you provide minimal input data, actual results and desired results and we can just copy/paste and test then helping will be easier and quicker.

Comment: I already read the documents and looked over to see if there was any similar problem. The possibles solutions are only done with JSON inside MongoDB environment. I'm updating the question to make more clear

Comment: Thanks - being able to just copy test data (format of your choice) and code to execute to reproduce the issue will go a long way.

Comment: Thanks for the help @DaveStSomeWhere. Sometimes we are very involved with the problem and we think it'll be easy for others to understand.

Comment: Looking at the data - it is very messy with all the quotes. What/where is the raw data?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere it is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U4u8UUSzTlsqn-2jY5UGiPY8mHNAOlFS/view?usp=sharing